# Create S3 only user

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a S3 only user who will by definition have no access to any other resource. The user can upload and download files from S3. I have created a basic template that can be found here...

https://github.com/shantanuo/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/IAM/IAM_Users_Groups_and_Policies.yaml

But it is allowing access to cloudformation that is not necessary in my case. I have read the following pages, but do not know how to include them in my template.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-user.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudForation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-group.html

What are the minimum parameters required to create a S3 only user?

---

Update:
Here is the cloudformation code that I tried and the error that I got:

error message: The following resource(s) failed to create: [CFNRole, CFNUser]. . Rollback requested by user.

The template:

```
Parameters:
  NewUsername:
    NoEcho: 'false'
    Type: String
    Description: New account username
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '41'
    ConstraintDescription: the username must be between 1 and 41 characters
  Password:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Type: String
    Description: New account password
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '41'
    ConstraintDescription: the password must be between 1 and 41 characters

Resources:
  CFNUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      LoginProfile:
        Password: !Ref 'Password'
      UserName : !Ref 'NewUsername'
  CFNRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties :
      PermissionsBoundary : arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
      RoleName : 'myPermissionBoundary'
  CFNKeys:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref 'CFNUser'

Outputs:
  AccessKey:
    Value: !Ref 'CFNKeys'
    Description: AWSAccessKeyId of new user
  SecretKey:
    Value: !GetAtt [CFNKeys, SecretAccessKey]
    Description: AWSSecretAccessKey of new user
```

I have checked this link, but not sure how to include the policy in my current template.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/

Comment: Firstly, are you sure that you wish to create this user via a CloudFormation template? It means that the stack must be running whenever you want that user. Typically, IAM Users are created manually in the IAM console and then credentials are given to the person or application that will be using the IAM User. Secondly, would I be correct in assuming that you copied the template from somewhere rather than writing it yourself? The policy is quite clearly granting CloudFormation permissions, but none for S3. Are you personally familiar with how IAM policies work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicit giving your new user access to Cloudformation in your template.
You have this section:

```
  CFNUserPolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: CFNUsers
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: ['cloudformation:Describe*', 'cloudformation:List*', 'cloudformation:Get*']
          Resource: '*'
      Groups: [!Ref 'CFNUserGroup']
  CFNAdminPolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: CFNAdmins
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: cloudformation:*
          Resource: '*'
Groups: [!Ref 'CFNAdminGroup']
```

In which your allow statements specifically provide access to Cloudformation. If you are trying to give access to s3 then why are you giving access to Cloudformation?

If you want a user to have access to s3 only, and going further one specific s3 bucket then your policy would look something like this (note this is in json):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                      ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want your user to have access to all buckets, then your policy would look more like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1557048549844",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

See this source: https://objectivefs.com/howto/how-to-restrict-s3-bucket-policy-to-only-one-aws-s3-bucket